# Button set to wrap content occupies more space than it needs

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a layout for my application and I encounter the following problem.

In my layout file

[image: http://gyazo.com/6b5aee107702c46637d9b799ab9170c6.png]

But when I put it in my Fragment (via a ListView, or just with , it looks like this:

[image]

category.xml (template to populate ListView afterwards)

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/second_grey">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:text="@string/sport"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/see_more"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="0.99">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/football"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer2">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/basketball"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer3">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tennis"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/second_grey"
tools:context="com.favega.groups.MainActivity$CategoryFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/category"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></include>
```

Comment: try to set `android:layout_width="wrap_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in `fragment_main.xml`

Comment: remove this for your textview 'android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"' and try..

Comment: @chintankhetiya Where do you mean? On the <include> or on the RelativeLayout?

Comment: @kalyanpvs My TextView does not have such properties

Comment: @zyngawow for relative layout

Comment: @chintankhetiya you can not set a main layout to wrap_parent.

Comment: @zyngawow try to use `TextView` instead of `Button` check my ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..  Use `TextView` instead of `Button`  if you use `Button` **defaultly it'll take much of size**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="see_more"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: That fixes it. Could you elaborate on why the Button asks for so much space?

Comment: @zyngawow normally `Button` will get 50 to 55 dp height that's why it gets that much of size.

Comment: How could I make the background extend a bit more in terms of width? I'd like about 1dp on each side

Comment: Thanks! now I have another problem (if you know what causes it, then I don't need to open a new question). The ImageViews show on the UI, but when put in a ListView, they don't show.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  padding from relative layout of fragment_main.xml